# Remove background color on UITableViewAccessory

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I added [Chameleon](https://github.com/ViccAlexander/Chameleon#contrasting-colors) to a project and it works well, for the most part. One issue I've stumbled into when setting a theme for a project is a background being placed  on UITableViewCell accessories.

Here's what my accessory looks like with the `ChameleonFramework` theme enabled:

[image]

My desired accessory color is blue with no background. Chameleon seems to invert these.

I also opened up Debug View Hierarchy to see what's going on. I can "see" the problem, but I can't figure out how to get at the accessory view's background to change it back to `UIColor.white`, nor can I figure out how to change the checkmark to `UIColor.blue`

[image]

I've tried to tinker with the tint of the accessory with the following command in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
cell.tintColor = UIColor.blue
```

I also tried changing the background of the `accessoryView`:

```
cell.accessoryView!.tintColor = UIColor.blue
cell.accessoryView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

I also tried changing the tint of the `tableView`:

```
tableView.tintColor = UIColor.blue
```

Any other ideas how I'd go about changing this are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try using cell.accessoryView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

Comment: Thanks. I tried that already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is a bug with Chameleon that is presently being worked on.

Digging around in Debug View Hierarchy, I saw that the checkmark was drawn as a `UIButton`. Rather than changing it on the `MyViewController`, I opted to change the UIButton class appearance in AppDelegate when it's contained in a `UITableViewCell`.

I was able to resolve my problem by calling the following commands from AppDelegate:

```
    UIButton.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UITableViewCell.classForCoder() as! UIAppearanceContainer.Type]).backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    UIButton.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UITableViewCell.classForCoder() as! UIAppearanceContainer.Type]).tintColor = FlatBlue()
```

Answer (score 1):

When using [Chameleon-RCI 2.1.0.2](https://components.xamarin.com/view/Chameleon-RCI) with [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/) I had the same problem when using `UITableViewCellAccessory.DetailDisclosureButton`.

```
UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("A");
if (cell == null)
{
        cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, "A");
        cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DetailDisclosureButton;
}
```

Similar to Adrian's answer but with C# the fix was the following in the `AppDelegate` class.

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // If not required for your application you can safely delete this method

    UIColor secondaryColor = ChameleonColor.FlatWatermelon;
    Chameleon.SetGlobalTheme(ChameleonColor.FlatMint, secondaryColor, ContentStyle.Contrast);

    UIButton.UIButtonAppearance buttonAppearance = UIButton.AppearanceWhenContainedIn(new Type[] { typeof(UITableViewCell) });
    buttonAppearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
    buttonAppearance.TintColor = secondaryColor;

    return (true);
}
```